# Ubuntu 13.10 big problem with privilegies

Tags: chromebook

I have HP 14 chromebook(with haswell celeron processor and 4 gb of ram, 4g), all is okay when i installed ubuntu 13.10 saucy with crouton script i didn't got any errors, but when i'm trying to install something, it says that i don't have privilegies, what should i do?  Thanks!

Comment: How are you installing; terminal or Software Center? Did you run as `sudo`? Are you a memeber of the `sudo` group?

Comment: I'm instaling with software center. Then it says authentication error, you don't have privilegies.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken installing Ubuntu using Crouton is off-topic here, you might have more luck asking in [unix.se] or [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)
2. Type (or copy and paste)

   sudo software-center
3. Type your password

In case you are not part of the sudo group, you must add your user to it